# MyBatis: How to return custom map

Tags: spring-mybatis

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `constant` (
  `type` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `param` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`type`,`param`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I want get the param as map key and the value as the map value, but a little confused about getting a simple way.

My code:

```
@Select("select param, value from constant where type = #{type}")
@MapKey("param")
Map<String, String> getConstantByType(@Param("type") String type);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a result handler for this to work.

When calling the method pass that result handler

ResultHandler Class:

```
public class SomeResultHandler implements ResultHandler<Object> {


private Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

@Override
public void handleResult(ResultContext<?> resultContext) {
    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, Object> result = (Map<String, String>) resultContext.getResultObject();                     
        map.put(result.get("param").toString(), result.get("value").toString());
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        // exception handler
    }

}

public Map<String, String> getMap() {
    return map;
}
}
```

pass this ResultHandler with method call. I used Java Stack.